# File upload - multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to implement a few file uploader packages (raw php) in a dynamically loaded format, with a potentially unknown number of them on a page. I've pretty much looked at all the popular ones from flash based to everything in between but having the same problem.

I'm currently trying to work with [this](http://nghiadh.info/blog/html5-drag-and-drop-and-xhr-upload-34.html).

I have tried tricks I've read about like using `^=` in `getelementbyid` and also `"\\S*"` to ensure that the relevant div id is used by the javascript but I've had no success. I've also tried adding a class name to each div and using the getelementbyclass without success. I've searched all over for a solution but I'm just not getting it.

Either I'm doing it wrong or I'm completely lost ... I'm actually both!

If anyone can put me out of my misery or send me down the right direction I'd really appreciate as I've been trying to find a solution for a while.

The HTML portion is presented like so:

```
<p id="upload" class="hidden"><label>Drag & drop not supported, but you can still upload via this input field:<br><input type="file"></label></p>
  <p id="filereader">File API & FileReader API not supported</p>
  <p id="formdata">XHR2's FormData is not supported</p>
  <p id="progress">XHR2's upload progress isn't supported</p>
  <p>Upload progress: <progress id="uploadprogress" min="0" max="100" value="0">0</progress></p>
  <p>Drag an image from your desktop on to the drop zone above to see the browser both render the preview, but also upload automatically to this server.</p>
```

I intend to dynamically generate it via PHP into something like, where $inc is a php variable in a loop, e.g id="filereader$inc

The issue, I believe is where the javascript will only handle pre-defined or one instance of the uploader untill modified otherwise

E.g: filereader: document.getElementById('filereader')

Comment: Could you post somecode, to understand the problem a bit better?

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to post more than ~500 characters here but the link with the code I'm trying to use is here: http://nghiadh.info/blog/html5-drag-and-drop-and-xhr-upload-34.html

Comment: The issue is I'm trying to dynamically create the html div id's but the javascript will only work with one instance, e.g filereader: document.getElementById('filereader')  ... I need to implement something like filereader: document.getElementById('filereader*') if you know what I mean?

Comment: Why do you need multiple instances? Is it to allow multiple uploads?

Comment: you dont need more instances of filereader. since the file is send right after dropping on the field, it can always use the same input field, check out my answer of yesterday there you can find the basic idea, how you can use multiple dropzone with one input-field .... i hope it helps

Comment: Hi wanted to ask did a solution work for you, or did you find a bettter solution, if so please share. THX :)

Comment: Hello, do you have a solution? Can you share it? Or did one of ours help you?

Answer (score 0):

Okay if i understand it correct, you want to use Drag And Drop fields in differnt parts of your page.

so the short answer is, you would have to add the events to every div, that should have this functionality.**since the upload works automatically you just need one file input field**

*only the dropzones must be copied(but only if you want, more dropzone) and their evens must be adjusted*

**Ps.: the html part stays the same as in the blog (plus the div with id holder [and holder2 for the second dropzone], which seem to have been omitted)**

example:

```
// tested on Chrome 26+
....
if (tests.dnd) { 
  holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
  holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
  holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  this.className = '';
  e.preventDefault();
  readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }
  //.... other drop spots example need the same events ....
  holder2.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
  holder2.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
  holder2.ondrop = function (e) {
      this.className = '';
      e.preventDefault();
      readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }
} else {
 ...
}
...
```

this works, but you could make it niceer using jQuery or so.

i hope it helps

**Edit:**
If ou want to send files to differnt server-side-scripts you would have to "modify" the function *readfiles* in te onDrop event

example(possible solution, not very clean):

```
// tested on Chrome 26+
 ....
 holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  this.className = '';
  e.preventDefault();
  readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files, "script_1.php");
  }
 ...
 function readfiles(files, posturl) {
 ...
   // now post a new XHR request
  if (tests.formdata) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', posturl);
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Or you could post to the same file, but using a flag to determin on the server from where the file came.

P.s.: you probably know, but still, this Codesnipplets and the one form the blog, need cleanup for production use.

all the best

Answer (score 0):

That Javascript code won't work with multiple instances because it uses the `getElementById` method which returns only one element (the first match it finds).

It's also worth mentioning that the JS code won't work for many users (about half, I believe) because it relies on the File API which isn't supported by IE9 and below.

To make that code work with multiple instances, it must be either refactored so as not to rely on element IDs, or you must generate multiple copies with unique elment IDs with the server side code. In PHP, that would involve using a `for` or `foreach` loop similar to this:

```
<?php

for (i=0; $i<$something; i++) {
  echo <<<EOB
  var holder = document.getElementById('holder$i'),
    tests = {
    filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',   
    dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),
    formdata: !!window.FormData,
    progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
    }, 
    support = {
    filereader: document.getElementById('filereader$i'),
    formdata: document.getElementById('formdata$i'),
    progress: document.getElementById('progress$i')
    },
// snipped for space
EOB;
}
```

I don't recommend either course of action, primarily because it still won't work at all with a large number of users. Instead, I suggest using a different upload library.

I've been similarly dissatisfied with JS file upload libraries, so I wrote one that supports IE7+ (theoretically IE6, but not tested), progress bars (with fallback options for handling IE9 and below), and allows multiple instances.

It does not, however, support drag and drop uploading, so if that's a requirement, it won't suit your needs. For what it's worth, here it is (link to live demo at the top):

https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader